# Is this WebSockets approach correct?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I want to create this routine:

1. I access the /receiver (Receiver)
2. Receiver is listening for 'hello' event
3. I access the /emitter (Emitter) from another tab
4. Emitter fires the 'hello' event
5. Receiver says alert("Hello world") when 'hello' event is fired

Is it possible using WebSockets? I want to make the API server with Python, and the client with JavaScript.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python very well, but you could do both back end and front end with javascript using http://socket.io/
In that website there are a lot of good examples similar to the one you were telling us here!

Comment: If you want different tabs to communicate, you should try [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) instead of WebSockets.

Comment: @oriol Thank you, I will search more about this API.

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone Thanks! I will use Socket.io with python on the server side \o/

Comment: @matheusb Sadly there isn't much browser support yet, so you might have to wait some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webSockets connect client and server.  The do not directly connect two web pages in two different tabs.

It is possible that two web pages in two different tabs could each connect to the server and the server could then route messages sent from one web page to the other web page.  That's how a typical chat program works (which is a classic demo app for webSockets).

Yes, this is possible to build with a server in Python and client in Javascript web page.

You can certainly find many libraries written for webSockets in Python with your own search.  Browser Javascript already has webSocket support built in.  Many people choose to use socket.io which is a higher-level library built on top of webSocket and there are implementations for socket.io in many languages (including Javascript for the browser and Python for the server).

Comment: That's nice! What I need:

[Flow](http://i.imgur.com/nCmzcQv.jpg)

The emitter needs say hello to receiver. Simple. And yes, emitter are in another tab, but not have problem call the server.

I just no want that the receiver keep checking the server each 5 or 10 seconds :)

Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that I can use Socket.io with Python. I thought this is a Node.js/Client scenario.

Comment: @matheusb - While socket.io was originally written in Javascript, there are implementations of socket.io in many languages.  Here's one for a Python server: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is used when you need a persistent, web-friendly connection with or without a browser.  If you just need to merely communicate among tabs in the same browser instance, you can use localStorage (which fires an StorageEvent event) even if you are offline.

If you potentially need the emitter to be accessed by another browser out on the web, or if the emitter was not a browser web-app (e.g., an IoT use case), then you would need WebSocket.  Then one good solution would be a simple publish/subscribe mechanism using WebSocket.  Here's a good Angular library that a colleague wrote that might help you:

https://github.com/kaazing/tutorials

Full disclosure: I work for Kaazing